# codeigniter : inserting data/record into 2 tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have 2 tables 'pengguna' and 'mahasiswa' and then 1 have a form which is 1 form inserting into 2 tables, so far i manage to insert the data but when it has to do with "primary key" and "foreign key" it has problem, as u can see from code below `id_pengguna` from table `pengguna` is a **primary key** and `id_pengguna` from table `mahasiswa` is a **foreign key** the problem is when i inserting the data, `id_pengguna` from `pengguna` has it value while in table `mahasiswa` it has no value, below are my code, is there any simple way or am i doing something wrong?

**PENGGUNA TABLE**
[image]
**MAHASISWA TABLE**
[image]

> **Controller**

```
public function insertMahasiswa(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $data1 = array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'password'=>$password,
            'level'=>3,
        );
    $nim = $this->input->post('nim');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $telepon = $this->input->post('telepon');
    $data = array(
            'nim'=>$nim,
            'nama_mahasiswa'=>$nama,
            'email'=>$email,
            'telepon'=>$telepon,
        );
    $insert = $this->MMahasiswa->create('pengguna',$data1);
    $insert1 = $this->MMahasiswa->create('mahasiswa',$data);
    redirect(site_url('mahasiswa/data?balasan=1'));
}
```

> **MODEL**

```
function create($table,$data){
    $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return last insert id form your model file

**In model**

```
function create($table,$data){
    $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();// return last insert id
}
```

**In controller**

```
$id_pengguna = $this->MMahasiswa->create('pengguna',$data1);
    $data = array(
                'nim'=>$nim,
                'nama_mahasiswa'=>$nama,
                'email'=>$email,
                'telepon'=>$telepon,
                'id_pengguna'=>$id_pengguna// add last insert id to mahasiswa table
            );
        $insert1 = $this->MMahasiswa->create('mahasiswa',$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting data to the 2nd table i.e. `mahasiswa` you need to grab the primary id created after insertion of data in table 1 (`pengguna`).

This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Grabbing last insert id using codeigniter's `insert_id()` function.

   ```
   function create($table,$data) {
       $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
       return $this->db->insert_id(); } // return last insert id
   ```
2. After inserting the data in 1st table, get the id of the row which has the same `username`. (For this you must have unique usernames in `username` column) This will return the corresponding id.
   Note: You can also do this with email column.

Source/Reference: Detailed explanation - [Inserting data in 2 tables through 1 Form - CodeIgniter](http://webolute.com/blog/programming/inserting-data-2-tables-1-form-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this (only few changes)

controller.php

```
public function insertMahasiswa(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

    $data1 = array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'password'=>$password,
            'level'=>3,
        );

    $nim = $this->input->post('nim');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $telepon = $this->input->post('telepon');

    $data = array(
            'nim'=>$nim,
            'nama_mahasiswa'=>$nama,
            'email'=>$email,
            'telepon'=>$telepon,
        );
    $insert = $this->MMahasiswa->create('pengguna',$data1);
    $insert1 = $this->MMahasiswa->create('mahasiswa',$data);

    $insert = $this->MMahasiswa->create('pengguna',$data1,'mahasiswa',$data);

    redirect(site_url('mahasiswa/data?balasan=1'));
}
```

model.php

```
function create($table1, $data1, $table2, $data2){
    $this->db->insert($table1, $data1);
    $id_table1    = $this->db->insert_id();

    array_unshift($data2, array('id_pengguna'=>$id_table1));

    $this->db->insert($table2, $data2);
    $id_table2    = $this->db->insert_id();

    $return_data  = array($table1 => $id_table1, $table2 => $id_table2);

    return $returndata;
}
```