# Codeigniter - inserting into multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am having problems with a booking form in Codeigniter; when a visitor makes a booking, the details are supposed to be inserted into two tables in a database ('reservation', and 'period', there is an FK from 'reservation' to 'period').

When I try to make the booking, nothing appears in the database, and I can't tell if it a problem with the form, or between the controller and model (there are no errors thrown - just nothing in the db). I tried to follow the logic from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709801/codeigniter-inserting-data-record-into-2-tables).

here is my form (gite-booking-form.php):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gite booking form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('GiteCtl/giteBookingForm'); ?>

<h5>Select a gite:</h5>
<?php
$gitenames = array('giteA', 'giteB', 'giteC', 'giteD');
$gitename = isset($_POST['gitename']) && in_array($_POST['gitename'], $gitenames) ? $_POST['gitename'] : 'giteA';

echo '<select name="gitename">';
foreach ($gitenames as $option) {
    echo '<option value="' . $option . '"' . (strcmp($option, $gitename) == 0 ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $option . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>

<h5>Start date</h5>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo set_value('start_date'); ?>"/>

<h5>End date</h5>
<input type="date" value="<?php echo set_value('end_date'); ?>"/>


<div><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

my model (Gite.php):

```
<?php

class Gite extends CI_Model
{


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }




    public function reservationInsert($table, $data)
    {
        $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);

        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }


}
```

and the controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class GiteCtl extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('Gite');
        $this->load->library('calendar');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('Visitors');
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn');

        if (!isset($isLoggedIn) || $isLoggedIn != TRUE) {
            echo 'In order to book a gite, you must first login';
            echo 'button: visitor-login.php'; // I will add this later
        } else {
            $this->giteBookingForm();
        }
    }

    public function giteBookingForm()
    {


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gite_selection', 'gite_select', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'startDate', 'required', array('required' => 'You must choose a %s.'));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('end_date', 'endDate', 'required', array('required' => 'You must provide an %s.')
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('gite-booking-form');


        } else {


            $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
            $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
            $isHauteSaison = 1;
            $isWeekend = 1;

            $period_data = array(

                'start_date' => $start_date,
                'end_date' => $end_date,
                'isHauteSaison' => $isHauteSaison,
                'isWeekend' => $isWeekend

            );



            $gite_selection = $this->input->post('gite_selection');
            $visitor_email = $this->session['visitorName'];
            $price = 100.00;


            $period_id = $this->Gite->reservationInsert('period', $period_data);

            $reservation_data = array(
                'gite_selection' => $gite_selection,
                'visitor_email' => $visitor_email,
                'price' => $price,
                'period' => $period_id
            );


            $insert = $this->Gite->reservationInsert('reservation', $reservation_data);


        }
    }


}
```

Thanks,
E.

Comment: Have you tried `if (!$query) die(print_r($this->db->error(),true));` in your `reservationInsert` method?

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that wrapping your call of `reservationInsert` method with `trans_start` and `trans_complete` would be much better, 

`$this->db->trans_start();
$this->Gite->reservationInsert(...);
$this->Gite->reservationInsert(...);
$this->db->trans_complete();`

This way, if one query produces an error, the other insert would be rolled back.

Comment: thanks for suggestons - I've tried both; still nothing being insert into the database, but no errors neither, so I guess the problem is between the controller and the model (or the form and the controller). The search continues...

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was the form; the php for retrieving data from the form was more complicated than I thought:

```
<h5>Select a gite:</h5>
<?php
$gitenames = array('giteA','giteB','giteC','giteD');
$gitename = isset($_POST['gitename']) && in_array($_POST['gitename'],$gitenames)?$_POST['gitename']:'giteA';

echo '<select name="gitename">';
foreach($gitenames as $option) {
    echo '<option value="'.$option.'"'.(strcmp($option,$gitename)==0?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.$option.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>

<h5>Start date</h5>


<input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date" value="<?php echo isset($start_date) ? set_value('start_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))) : set_value('start_date');   ?>">


<h5>End date</h5>

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date" value="<?php echo isset($end_date) ? set_value('end_date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date))) : set_value('end_date');   ?>">
```